# ruby: given an ip address, find out the City and State

Tags: ruby, geocoding

I've been searching for about ten minutes, haven't found a simple code sample yet.

Basically, I'm looking for something like this:

```
puts Geocoder.lookup_location_by_ip("76.95.251.102")

result California, USA
```

So a ruby method that decodes an ip address in to its City, State.

Comment: You can use [geoip](https://github.com/cjheath/geoip) gem

Comment: Keep in mind that looking up addresses by IP addresses is very inaccurate. When I try @ProgNoob solution with my current IP address, then it resolves to an address in a different state more than 250km away from my current position.

Comment: This gem just search IP location according to library.  Other gems works same, as I know.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Ten minutes? That long? IP addresses don't decode into Cities or States. What sort of accuracy do you need? There are attempts to try to map them by people but they can be wildly inaccurate because IPs are assigned to providers and their ranges can be used anywhere they want.

Comment: this question isn't bad enough that it deserved 3 downvotes. You people are monsters.

Comment: exactly my sentiments too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps:

1. Install geocoder using:

   ```
   gem install geocoder
   ```
2. In a Ruby script use:

   ```
   require "geocoder"
   puts Geocoder.address('76.95.251.102')   #Change the ip address accordingly.
   ```
3. Run the script to get the city, state, zipcode, country.

   ```
   # => Bellflower, CA 90706, United States
   ```

Comment: You don't need `;` to end a line in Ruby, and comments start with `#` not `//`.